# Child Numbers: Items follow section numbers

Tags: numbering

I'd like the numbering of items in the document to reflect the numbers of the sections in which they are found. In the MWE, the numbering is

Section 1

1.

2.

Section 2

1.

2.

What I want is:

Section 1

1.1

1.2

Section 2

2.1

2.2

How can I achieve this?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
 
\begin{document}
%\maketitle
%\section{}
%\subsection{}

\section{Structure}
\begin{enumerate}

\item
first point
\item
Second point

\end{enumerate}

\section{Circus Tents}
\begin{enumerate}
\item
number
\item
kind
\end{enumerate}



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways to achieve this. First, if you're not into using packages, adjust `\labelenumi` by adding this to your document preamble:
`\renewcommand\labelenumi{\thesection.\theenumi.}`. It prefixes `\thesection` to the default label.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand\labelenumi{\thesection.\theenumi.}

\begin{document}

\section{Structure}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item
  First point

  \item
  Second point
\end{enumerate}

\section{Circus Tents}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item
  Number

  \item
  Kind
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

This process is made a little more easy using [`enumitem`](//ctan.org/pkg/enumitem):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\thesection.\arabic*.}

\begin{document}

\section{Structure}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item
  First point

  \item
  Second point
\end{enumerate}

\section{Circus Tents}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item
  Number

  \item
  Kind
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This worked well. Assuming no aversion to packages, which would you recommend?

Comment: Go with the second ([`enumitem`](//ctan.org/pkg/enumitem)) approach, since it adds other functionality that you may be interested in. It is the go-to package for list management.